# .net core aws Lambda No error, but Lambda halts

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, lambda, .net-core

I've built a .NET Core aws Lambda that reads an xml file from S3 and does some processing on it.  When I run the lambda locally it works without issue; however, when I upload the Lambda and attempt to execute it, it halts trying to get the contents of the file and there are no errors showing in cloudwatch.  Here is my code that is having issues:

```
public async Task<string> GetFileContentsFromS3(string bucket, string key)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting File Contents for Bucket: " + bucket + " and Key: " + key);

                GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucket,
                    Key = key
                };

                Console.WriteLine("request: " + request.BucketName + " | " + request.Key);
                using (GetObjectResponse responseObject = await S3Client.GetObjectAsync(request))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("In Response Object");
                    using (Stream responseStream = responseObject.ResponseStream)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("In Response Stream");
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Successfully got File Contents");
                            return reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            return string.Empty;
        }

    }
```

When I look at my cloudwatch logs I can see the output from this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Getting File Contents for Bucket: " + bucket + " and Key: " + key); and this: Console.WriteLine("request: " + request.BucketName + " | " + request.Key);
```

I do not get anything after that, and the logs note that the function ended before finishing.  It's not hitting timeout as that is set to 30 seconds and my memory allocation should be sufficient.  Also, I've given my IAM user full control for S3 so that shouldn't be an issue.  I think it's this line:

```
using (GetObjectResponse responseObject = await S3Client.GetObjectAsync(request))
```

That is causing the issue, but I don't know of another way to get the contents of the file or what could be the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Console.WriteLine, try to use the Logger that is part of the ILambdaContext (second parameter of your entry point). If your lambda has the necessary rights configured, it will output to CloudWatch.